# asset validation failed 90476 in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

Ive just got this error: asset validation failed 90476

The error is appearing in the Mac Transporter App.
It's an app for iOs and iPad OS.
The App builds like normal and it says that it's getting build correctly but when I'm trying to upload it it fails with this error message.

Full error message:

ERROR: Asset validation failed (90476) Invalid bundle. Because your app supports Multitasking on iPad, you need to include the SplashScreen launch storyboard file in your app-name bundle. Use UILaunchScreen instead if the app’s MinimumOSVersion is 14 or higher and you prefer to configure the launch screen without storyboards. For details, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uilaunchstoryboardname (ID: f2bc540e-6148-4983-9691-a9a3997a0ea6)

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that Xcode automatically set 'Launch screen interface file base name' to LaunchScreen.storyboard. The solution is to remove the extension and provide only LaunchScreen (or blank).